# P vs. NP and Pseudorandom Bit Generators

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, derandomization, p-vs-np

According to an [article on pseudorandom number generators (PRNG) by Jeff Lagarias](https://doi.org/10.1214/ss/1177011081), he states that trying to prove that a PRNG is unpredictable (secure) is just "as hard" as trying to prove that P!=NP. If it is considered impossible to prove mathematically that some bit sequence is random then it should be mathematically impossible to prove P!=NP, right? Are these two problems really equivalent? If they are then why all the hoopla over P vs NP, you can never prove it either way according to these definitions.

Comment: @Paul, Could you please provide a link to the cited article?

Comment: @turkistany: I added the link.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies,adding links and editing. You guys are too fast for me!

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic since this seems be a speculative attempt on $P$ vs $NP$ problem. See the later question posted by OP: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/p-vs-np-via-psuedo-random-number-generators

Comment: Please see the meta-discussion: [Is it ok to ask about the correctness of preprints on crank-friendly topics?](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/274/is-it-ok-to-ask-about-the-correctness-of-preprints-on-crank-friendly-topics)

Comment: @Kaveh: I don't see any problem with this particular question, other than perhaps the level.

Comment: @Joe, I don't have a problem with this question by itself although I don't like *"why all the hoopla over P vs NP, you can never prove it either way according to these definitions."* (a complete misconception). In the other question OP states that he does not know anything about *computer science* (not just theory) and seems to be an outsider to CS trying to win the million award (I would say these are crank-like symptoms). Let me put it differently, let's ask the OP why he is interested in this question? (and the answer seems to be he wants to win a million dollar by solving $P$ vs $NP$).

Comment: [continued] I am not sure if I could explain my feelings about this question, I guess I probably look too harsh sometimes but I feel that being strict on these issues is essential in keeping the level of site professional. (you might understand what I mean if you have seen the discussions on complexity blog a while ago.)

Comment: @Kaveh: I don't think he was serious. I took the comment about winning millions (which is actually only in a follow-up) as being a joke.

Comment: @Joe: Hmmm, in that case ... :)

Comment: see also research on [natural proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_proof) which shows the apparently strong connection between proving PRNG security and P=?NP

Answer (score 14):

There is a bit of an issue with your question. You are using the words unpredictable and secure interchangeably, which would seem to imply that you mean "unpredictable to a polynomial-time bounded  adversary". This is not at all the same thing as being truly unpredictable, since clearly there is a function (in this case the PRNG) which generates them. So this is not related to any issue with proving that the sequence is 'truly' random in some sense. Rather, what you really need is that given the prior output of the PRNG it is computationally hard to predict the next number.

This formulation is clearly related to P vs NP since clearly calculating a sequence of $m$ pseudo-random numbers using the generator is in FP (the functional version of P) when the key $k$ to the PRNG is known. However given a set of $m$ sequential pseudo-random numbers outputted by the device, the problem of finding $k$ is clearly in FNP (the functional version of NP).

Thus proving that it is computationally easy to generate the pseudo random numbers but computationally hard to infer the key from a sample of the output of the PRNG would imply that $FP \neq FNP$ (and hence $P\neq NP$).

Comment: Nice answer. Would it make any difference if the randomness of PRNG defined as "unpredictable to any subexponential-time bounded adversary"?

Comment: @turkistany: Yes, since there are functions which are not believed to be in P but for which sub-exponential time algorithms are known, which could be used as the basis of the PRNG. For example, factoring, which has an algorithm which takes only $O(\exp(c n^{\frac{1}{3}}(\log n)^\frac{2}{3}))$.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that a sub-exponential time attacker may in fact be even more powerful than NP, since they can potentially use more than polynomial space.

Answer (score 10):

Every cryptographically-secure pseudo-random bit generator $G$ is a one-way function; since given the output $y$ of $G(\cdot)$ on some input (seed) $s$, it is computationally infeasible to obtain $s$ from $y$. (Otherwise, the generator is not cryptographically-secure). So we have:

**cryptographically-secure pseudo-random bit generator exists** $\Rightarrow$ **one-way functions exist**.

The existence of **one-way functions** is a stronger assumption than $\rm{P}\ne\rm{NP}$. That is:

**one-way functions exist** $\Rightarrow$ $\rm{P}\ne\rm{NP}$.

(For more info on this, see the [Status of Impagliazzo's Worlds](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1026/873).)

---

#### Edit:

[Impagliazzo, Levin, and Luby](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=73007.73009) showed that the reverse holds under non-uniform assumptions; that is:

**one-way functions exist** $\Rightarrow$ **cryptographically-secure pseudo-random bit generator exists**.

(here, the security is with reference to non-uniform adversaries.)

[Håstad](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=100216.100270) generalized this to uniform adversaries.

Joining forces, [Håstad, Impagliazzo, Levin, and Luby](http://link.aip.org/link/?SMJCAT/28/1364/1) showed that:

**cryptographically-secure pseudo-random bit generator exists** *if and only if* **one-way functions exist**.