# P vs. NP via psuedo-random number generators

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, derandomization, p-vs-np

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [P vs. NP and Pseudorandom Bit Generators](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2839/p-vs-np-and-pseudorandom-bit-generators)

Hello again , and thank you all for making this website a great vehicle for knowledge exchange. So my question is , are you trying to tell me that all I have to do is design a psuedo-random number generator that puts out a random bit stream such that no analysis of the output bits can ever have any correlation at all to the imput bits(a one way function) and I can win a million dollars? You got to be kidding me , right? I have to say right off the bat that I know nothing about computer science but I do know a little bit about electronic design and I must confess that this does not seem to be that difficult. I will have a design for

Comment: Is there something missing at the end of the post?

Comment: @Paul: You are seemingly referring to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2839/873. Why you started a new topic? You could have edited your original question.

Comment: "I have to say right off the bat that I know nothing about computer science ... and I must confess that this does not seem to be that difficult. I will have a design for ". Please read the FAQ. Crank-friendly topics like speculative proof attempts on $P$ vs $NP$ are NOT welcome. I am going to vote to close the other question also as off-topic for this site.

Comment: IMO we should not close a question just because someone claimed to have an amazing proof (or even a new approach) to a long-standing open problem, since he may really have something cool in his mind, and with some obstacles which he needs a little help here. However I voted to close this question, because it seems that there is no really question but a statement that he may have something new.

Comment: @Paul: Pseudo-random number generators are deterministic computations designed to mimic some of the statistics of true random sources. It is by definition impossible to have a deterministic computation where the output is randomly distributed when the input is fixed, and so what you propose is impossible at a fundamental level, independent of where or not P=NP.

Comment: @Hsien-Chih Chang: cstheory is a Q&A site and the SE sites are intentionally designed to discourage discussions. There has been a meta discussion on this issue and I think there was an agreement that crank-friendly topics like proof attempts on $P$ vs $NP$ (which are not peer-reviewed) are off-topic. Please see: [Is it ok to ask about the correctness of preprints on crank-friendly topics?](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/274/is-it-ok-to-ask-about-the-correctness-of-preprints-on-crank-friendly-topics)

Comment: @Kaveh: Thank you for pointing this out. I do know the policy now, and I'll follow it!