# A generalisation of one-wayness

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, cr.crypto-security, one-way-function, average-case-complexity

$\mathbf{NP}$-complete problems are worst-case hard. Their average-case counterpart are one-way functions. Is there an analogous one-wayness notion for $\mathbf{coNP}$-complete problems? More generally, a standard one-way function can be viewed as an average-case-hard (search) problem in $\mathbf{NP}$ relative to $\mathbf{P}$. Can this notion be extended to two arbitrary complexity classes?

Comment: While inverting a one-way function is hard-on-average, it does not mean that every hard-on-average problem represents a one-way function. Am I right?

Comment: **PS:** I'm interested in your motivation. Could you please [tell us why you care](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question/306#306)?

Comment: You may be interested in the following paper of Pavan Aduri et al: http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~pavan/papers/acwcnc.pdf

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks for the reference. It seems to be dealing with a lot of relevant topics.

Comment: @Pooya: From CLRS: "We define an **abstract problem** $Q$ to be a binary relation on a set $I$ of problem instances and a set $S$ of problem solutions." So, a problem is not a function, and a hard-on-average problem is not necessarily a one-way function.

Comment: @Pooya: In addition, it might be the case that hard-on-average problems exist, but one-way functions do not. See the definition of Pessiland in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1026/873.

Comment: As Sadeq said, it is not justified to call one-way functions the “average-case counterpart” of NP-complete problems.  Inverting a fixed one-way function is an example of hard-on-average problems (by definition), but there are other problems which are hard on average.  Because of this, I do not know what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. So the difference is if instance/solution pairs can be generated easily. Now if we always require this on top of average-case hardness, do we arrive at a reasonable generalisation of OWFs?